# Login for 64-bit boot-repair needed

Tags: boot, login, 64-bit

I'd like to use YannUbuntus 64-bit boot repair for the final stage of my linux / win10 dual boot. With the 64-bit boot-repair-disk the lubuntu UI prompts me for a login as Other. I've tried a wide range of possible guesses, but haven't found the right one. I've looked online and tried whatever suggestions I can find...
I've used 32bit boot repair a fair bit, but was never prompted to login... What's the password Yann? :-)

Comment: I can't picture what you mean by "*Lubuntu's UI prompts me for a login as Other*" unless you created a username labelled "Other".  What release are you talking about? as Lubuntu by default now only offers login for users with accounts (so is "Other" a name of a user that was created on your system?)

Comment: You can contact YannUbuntu [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Yannubuntu)

Comment: You can boot your Ubuntu live installer & just add Boot-Repair to it using the ppa. The ppa may be newer version, so I normally suggest users use the ppa version.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

> What's the password Yann?

I think you are asking in the wrong place.

You can contact Yannubuntu in any of these ways:

https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/profile.php?id=63523
https://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=485559

or by email directly at yannubuntu@gmail.com